# selenium in python Unable to locate element to click continue button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to add script to click continue option but its giving me this option what should I do next if anyone can help me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/deepak/PycharmProjects/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/login.php")

# identify username, password and signin elements
driver.find_element_by_name("LoginID").send_keys("3480199")

driver.find_element_by_name("NewPass").send_keys("12")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()

driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/battle_trainer.php")

# identify Enter Trainer Name/Number
driver.find_element_by_name("Trainer").send_keys("2502909")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nqap.png)

It works fine here but when I add again this line to click continue button

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbASJ.png)

then this gives me this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".submit"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)
```

Comment: I think the script needs to wait before you click last submit. would you try to put some sleep or wait?

Comment: i tried to add sleep script but it gives me integer error problem

Comment: 1) You should send the text to `driver.find_element_by_name("LoginID").send_keys("2502909")` element instead of `driver.find_element_by_name("Trainer").send_keys("2502909")`
But I do not understand why don't you fill the password and why are you clicking the `submit` button twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the xpath below for continue button. Its working for me

```
//input[@value='Continue >>']
```

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
```

Comment: i tried to add your script it still giving me the error

Comment: it worked for me without any wait. What error do you get

Comment: This is my entire code driver.find_element_by_name("LoginID").send_keys("3480199")
       driver.find_element_by_name("NewPass").send_keys("12")
       driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("//a[contains(.,'Trainer Battle')]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("Trainer").send_keys("2502909")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()        driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()

Comment: thank you so much it worked.   what script i can add to click restart option there?

Comment: this is the xpath for Restart battle link: //a[contains(.,'Restart Battle')]

Comment: if it helped you pls upvote my answer by selecting the upper arrow key